# Auto retrieve result form REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I am development user control that use REST API and `jquery` to pull data form custom data source , I will add the user control in a page and I need to refresh the result every 5 min to retrieve data , how to implement that

Comment: Use `setInterval` in your Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you build a self-invoking Function like

```
function poller(){

  [...]

  if(someConditionIsnTMet) setInterval(poller, timeToWait);
}
```